# How to add two viewModel class in xml with recycler view Adapter

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I need to add two ViewModel classes in a single recycler view and I did not get any solution yet. I don't know it is possible or not if you got any solution than answer me and suggest I tried to do like this :

```
public class PlannedListAdapter extends
RecyclerView.Adapter<PlannedListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<AddMedicineData> dataModelList;
    private Context context;
    public PlannedListAdapter(List<AddMedicineData> dataModelList, Context ctx) {
        this.dataModelList = dataModelList;
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        PlannedRecyclerItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.planned_recycler_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AddMedicineData dataModel = dataModelList.get(position);
       /* holder.itemRowBinding.timePill.setText();*/

        for (int j=0;j<dataModelList.get(position).getPilldates().size();j++){
            String timeList = dataModelList.get(position).getPilldates().get(j).getPilltime();
            Log.d("@@PillTimes", timeList);
            holder.itemRowBinding.timePill.setText(dataModel.getPilldates().get(j).getPilltime());
        }
        holder.bind(dataModel);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataModelList.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public PlannedRecyclerItemBinding itemRowBinding;
        public ViewHolder(PlannedRecyclerItemBinding itemRowBinding) {
            super(itemRowBinding.getRoot());
            this.itemRowBinding = itemRowBinding;
        }
        public void bind(Object obj) {
            itemRowBinding.setVariable(BR.medicineModel, obj);
            itemRowBinding.executePendingBindings();
        }
    } }
```

and in my XML I added another View Model Like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="medicineModel"
        type="com.kulsoft.care4cute.databinding.AddMedicineData" />

  <!--  <variable
        name="pillTakeModel"
        type="com.kulsoft.care4cute.models.MedicalModel.PilltakeModel" />-->
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_medicine"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/padding_10"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/padding_10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imgClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView

                    android:src="@drawable/clock"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_20dp">

                </ImageView>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imgClick"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensRegular
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="@{medicineModel.medName}"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensRegular>


                    <com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensSemiBold
                        android:id="@+id/timePill"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    </com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensSemiBold>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensThin
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@{`1 ` +medicineModel.medType}"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                </com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensThin>

                    <com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensThin
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@{medicineModel.medDose}"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensThin>

                    <com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensThin
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:text="@{medicineModel.medUnit}"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    </com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensThin>

                    <com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensThin
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Medication Reminder"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    </com.kulsoft.care4cute.fonts.OpenSensThin>

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lin_medicine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_10"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In XML I want to set a List of Model class that I have tried in adapter according to loop.

Thank you in Advance and I Appreciate your every answer and comment

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any errors already?

Setting multiple variables in binding is possible, there is no real difference when you are doing this from activity/fragment or adapter.

In general, setting 2nd variable just like you did with first one - should work. However, I am not getting why you are using loop there for setting text in your View.

Also, don't forget to build the project with just new variable in your XML in order to generate BR property

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       final AddMedicineData dataModel = dataModelList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
holder.itemRowBinding.timePill.setText(dataModel.getPilldates().get(0).getPilltime());
            holder.bind(dataModel);
        }
```

Comment: I am not getting an error but value inside the loop is repeating only last one

Comment: No error in binding I only want to get List data from inside model class and List also has model class

Comment: In your loop you are taking all values from dataModelList item, and setting to the same textView, so textView shows only the last value.

Comment: I am not really getting what is the expected result

Comment: yes I did I am getting many entries and set the last one only

Comment: Do you mean over all recyclerview items you have the same value set in text view, that is the last one?

Comment: In Log I am getting many value bc of for loop inside view holder adapter

Comment: First of all, you might want to use holder.getAdapterPosition() instead of position within onBindViewHolder,

Comment: Next, try to avoid any loops within onBindViewHolder

Comment: Ok let me try this one

Comment: how will I set time in Textview even I Can not add text in XML

Comment: I've updated my answer, try that one, it will use just the 1st item from the list of each object. Now, you should think of having a separate RecyclerView for each item to have there a list of subitems

Comment: Thank you It is working for me I appreciate your suggestion

Comment: Enjoy coding ! :D